# Bring Activity Front while phone is in CALL_STATE_RINGING

Tags: android

I am using PhoneStateListner to get the incoming call number I am getting the number successfully. But i want to play a video during incoming call, below code I am using to play video,

I am getting error

```
01-23 17:44:41.199: E/MediaPlayer-JNI(25145): Not Using QCMediaPlayer,setting qc_post_event to NULL...
01-23 17:44:41.199: E/MediaPlayer(25145): Uri is  <URL suppressed>
01-23 17:44:41.219: E/MediaPlayer(25145): error (1, -2147483648)
01-23 17:44:41.309: E/MediaPlayer(25145): Error (1,-2147483648)
01-23 17:44:41.319: D/VideoView(25145): Error: 1,-2147483648
01-23 17:44:49.228: E/MediaPlayer(25145): Uri is  <URL suppressed>
01-23 17:44:49.228: E/MediaPlayer(25145): error (1, -2147483648)
01-23 17:44:49.278: E/MediaPlayer(25145): Error (1,-2147483648)
01-23 17:44:49.278: D/VideoView(25145): Error: 1,-2147483648
01-23 17:46:13.127: E/MediaPlayer(25145): Uri is  <URL suppressed>
01-23 17:46:13.127: E/MediaPlayer(25145): error (1, -2147483648)
01-23 17:46:16.881: E/MediaPlayer(25145): Uri is  <URL suppressed>
01-23 17:46:16.891: E/MediaPlayer(25145): error (1, -2147483648)
01-23 17:46:16.932: E/MediaPlayer(25145): Error (1,-2147483648)
01-23 17:46:16.932: D/VideoView(25145): Error: 1,-2147483648
```

My code is

videoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
        mediaController = new MediaController(this);

```
    telephonyManager =(TelephonyManager)MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

    PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener()
    {
    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(state ==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING )
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT
                    |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT
                    |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(i);
            mediaController.setMediaPlayer(videoView);
             videopath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/bluetooth/charlie.mp4";
            videoView.setVideoPath(videopath);

            videoView.start();
            videoView.bringToFront();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Incoming call"+incomingNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
    }   
    };

    telephonyManager.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
```

It is playing video but at the backside,but I need that video at the front.